# DataTable print not have a border of table

Tags: php, jquery, html, printing, datatable

DataTable but when I use print (Ctrl+P) can not have a border of table.

[www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/sorting/custom/default.php](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/sorting/custom/default.php)

Please help me have the border of table

I thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define CSS for Print media. Please try it.

```
@media print {
    table, table tr, table td {
        border-top: #000 solid 1px;
        border-bottom: #000 solid 1px;
        border-left: #000 solid 1px;
        border-right: #000 solid 1px;
    }
}
```